# i don't want grid view empty when button click event call

Tags: c#, asp.net

you may see in photo that i attached, there is one dropdown and one button and two grid view. when i select dropdown value and than first grid will fill
than i select radio button and click on apply button than second grid will
 be fill. problem is start now again i select drop down it will display first grid and select radio button and click on button and display only new record and old will remove so i want both

[image]

```
    protected void btnapply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           SelectModel();

    }

    public void SelectModel()
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[6] { new DataColumn("Software"), new DataColumn("id"), new DataColumn("module"), new DataColumn("rdoread"), new DataColumn("rdoreadmodify"), new DataColumn("all") });
            foreach (GridViewRow row in Gridmodule.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    CheckBox chkRead = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("rdoread") as CheckBox);
                    CheckBox chkReadModify = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("rdoreadmodify") as CheckBox);
                    CheckBox chkAll = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("rdoall") as CheckBox);

                    if (chkRead.Checked)
                    {
                        string id = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblid") as Label).Text;
                        string module = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("lblmodule") as Label).Text;
                        bool read = true;
                        bool readmodify = false;
                        bool all = false;
                        string soft = (drpsoftware.SelectedItem.ToString());

                        dt.Rows.Add(soft, id, module, read, readmodify, all);
                    }

                    if (chkReadModify.Checked)
                    {
                        string id = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblid") as Label).Text;
                        string module = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("lblmodule") as Label).Text;
                        bool read = false;
                        bool readmodify = true;
                        bool all = false;
                        string soft = (drpsoftware.SelectedItem.ToString());

                        dt.Rows.Add(soft, id, module, read, readmodify, all);
                    }

                    if (chkAll.Checked)
                    {
                        string id = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblid") as Label).Text;
                        string module = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("lblmodule") as Label).Text;
                        bool read = false;
                        bool readmodify = false;
                        bool all = true;
                        string soft = (drpsoftware.SelectedItem.ToString());

                        dt.Rows.Add(soft, id, module, read, readmodify, all);
                    }

                }
            }
            gridselected.DataSource = dt;
            gridselected.DataBind();
        }
```

i want that when i press first time this button it fill grid and when i press again the same button it never erase previous data and fill new data with old .

Comment: You should remove the `if (IsPostBack)` condition in `SelectModel`. If you call `SelectModel` in `Page_Load`, you can put the condition in `Page_Load`.

Comment: just simple tell me that what i have to do if i don't want erase the data when i press on button

Comment: I don't know if your last comment was made after removing the `IsPostBack` condition from `SelectModel`. In any case, if that condition is present, the code inside of it will not be executed when you click the button. In other words, try the suggestion I made in my first comment.

Comment: you may see in photo that i attached,

Comment: please read again i change in it

Comment: Make a global `DataTable dt` and fill it with more info every click, instead off initializing it in the function